# Hidden formulas are visible when excel sheet is opened in Google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have created a local excel sheet in Microsoft excel in which i have used some formulas. I have hidden all the formulas used in it. But when i open the sheet via Google sheets one is able to see all the formulas clearly.

Is there any way we can hide the formulas from anywhere the sheet is opened.

Comment: if you want to share a google sheet you should use a secondary sheet with IMPORTRANGE formula. this way all your secret formulae will remain unknown from other people

Comment: One of the advantages or disadvantages of using files across programs... One way I get rid of passwords on some files... :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73682396/hidden-formulas-are-visible-when-excel-sheet-is-opened-in-google-sheet#comment130113910_73682396), using [**`importrange`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) produced an error:

> You don't have permissions to access that sheet.
> [Learn more](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340)

[image]

### What to do

**01** Convert the **xlxs** file into Google sheet file, by going to File > Save as Google sheets.

[image]

**02** Get the ID of the converted sheet and use it in the [**`importrange`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) formula in the shared spreadsheet in `A1` like this.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("Converted_spreadsheet_ID", "Converted_spreadsheet_SheetName!=1:1000")
```

Comment: @player0 see if you can edit this answer.